# draw image on canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am trying to put an image on a canvas. I read the following tutorial 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images 
and tried to do something similar to it
my canvas is `<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>`
and I have created the function

```
  function putImage(){
         var img = new Image();
         img.src = "./path.png"; 
         var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
         ctx.drawImage(img,8,8);            
  }
```

but the image is not appearing on the canvas.
I have printed the image path and it is correct, so I was able to eliminate this issue.
any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure the image path is correct? Are you getting any errors on the developer console/firebug?

Comment: yes 100% sure i printed it to the console and it is the right path
"./dir/image.png"

no errors in the console

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the tutorial, you're supposed to wrap your `ctx.drawImage()` inside `img.onload` like so

```
function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
  img.src = '/files/4531/backdrop.png';
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: To elaborate why you have to do this: When you set the `.src` attribute of an image, the image is requested from the server, but the program doesn't wait until the image has loaded. It keeps running, and when it comes to a ctx.drawImage method call which requires the not yet loaded image, it ignores this call.

Comment: Which is why you have to wait for the image to load, then give it a callback function which then draws the image now that it's loaded

Answer (score 2):

To add to Hass's answer: If you don't like the `onload` approach, you can `await` a `Promise`, like so:

```js
async function draw() {
  let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
  let url = "https://example.com/image.png";
  let img = new Image();
  await new Promise(r => img.onload=r, img.src=url);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like to use `Promise` or `onload` you can also use [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  });
  img.src = '/files/4531/backdrop.png';
}
```